# Is there any specific function in firebase v9 to make sure that user stays logged-in when the browser is closed?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to figure out how to make sure that the user stays logged in when he reopens
the browser & when he opens the site in a new tab. I've used an onAuthStateChanged listener for the user's auth actions. But I can't figure out the next step.

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signOut, onAuthStateChanged
} from 'firebase/auth';

import { auth, db} from '../firebaseConfig';
import { collection, addDoc, query, where, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

// LISTENS FOR YOUR AUTH STATES (SIGNUP, LOGOUT, LOGIN)
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if(user){
        //
    }else{
        // 
    }
})

export const SignUp = async (email, password) => {
    try {

        let response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        const userID = uuidv4();
        const userCollection = collection(db, 'users');
        const userData = {
            userID: userID,
            email: email,
        }
        await addDoc(userCollection, userData);
        return {
            // response: response,
            userID: userID,
            email: email,
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}


const getUserID = async (email) => {
    try {
        const userCollection = collection(db, 'users');
        const q = query(userCollection, where('email', '==', email));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
            throw new Error('User not found');
        }
        let docSnap = querySnapshot.docs[0];
        let {userDoc, userID} = docSnap.data();
       
        return userID;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export const Login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
       
        let response = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        const userID = await getUserID(email);
        localStorage.setItem('userID', userID);
        return response;
    }
    catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}



export const Logout = () => {

    try {
        signOut(auth);
        localStorage.removeItem('userID');
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}
```

Firstly I thought of setting the `browserSessionPersistence` but it didn't work also I can access the user objects due to `onAuthStateChanged`. If I'm not wrong I can check if the user `isAuthenticated` and do something so that the user stays logged in.

Comment: You could set a cookie in the browser with an expiration of one day, containing the means for authentication. Not for high security.

Comment: I'm not clear where you are stuck. You use the listener to get a callback to know when the user object first becomes available after they load the site again.  It's not available immediately.  Right now your listener is empty.

Comment: Yes, the listener is empty! I want to use some logic like cookies or anything that keeps the user loggedin after he/she reopens the browser!

Comment: Okay, what I did was instead of setting a cookie. I just used a useEffect in SignUp and Login Components and if a user is authenticated it redirects to the home page and if it's not it goes to login/signup @joop-eggen